# calculating the final length

Tags: java, string

The following code separates the duplicate names into 1 column and sum of numbers associated with the names into the second column.

Like :

```
   Nokia 21

   Blackberry 3

   Nimbus 30
```

from the array given in the program.

---

I want to know the final length of the array that contain these entries. In this case 3. How do i calculate that ?

```
package keylogger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayTester {

private static int finalLength = 0;
private static String Name[][];
private static String data[][] = { 
                               {"Nokia" , "7"},
                               {"Blackberry" ,"1"},
                               {"Nimbus","10"},
                               {"Nokia" , "7"},
                               {"Blackberry" , "1"},
                               {"Nimbus","10"},
                               {"Nokia" , "7"},
                               {"Blackberry" , "1"},
                               {"Nimbus","10"}

                          };  

public void calculator() {

    Name = new String[data.length][2];
    List<String> marked = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            Name[i][0] = data[i][0];
            Name[i][1] = data[i][1];
            String name = data[i][0];
            if(marked.contains(name)) {

                continue;
            }
            marked.add(name);
            int k = i + 1;
            int v = k;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length - v; j++) {
                String s = data[k][0];
                if(Name[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    Name[i][0] = s;
                    Integer z = Integer.parseInt(Name[i][1]) + Integer.parseInt(data[k][1]);
                    Name[i][1] = z.toString();
                }
                k++;
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayTester o = new ArrayTester();
    o.calculator();
    for(String s[] : Name) {
        for(String x : s) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i don't think i understand. do you just want to check how many distinct names you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the "problem" is poor coding. Your entire program, properly written, can be reduced to just 3 lines of code (5 if you include defining the array and printing the output):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data[][] = {{"Nokia", "7"}, {"Blackberry", "1"}, {"Nimbus", "10"},
        {"Nokia", "7"}, {"Blackberry", "1"}, {"Nimbus", "10"}, {"Nokia", "7"},
        {"Blackberry", "1"}, {"Nimbus", "10"}, {"Zebra", "78"}};

    HashMap<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String[] datum : data)
        totals.put(datum[0], new Integer(datum[1]) + (totals.containsKey(datum[0]) ? totals.get(datum[0]) : 0));
    System.out.println("There are " + totals.size() + " brands: " + totals);
}
```

Output:

```
There are 4 brands: {Nimbus=30, Zebra=78, Nokia=21, Blackberry=3}
```

Comment: what if there is another _unique_ brand ? Suppose there is one brand named `zebra 78`. At the end i wanted an array that contained unique brands with the total.

Comment: I think it should be totals.put(datum[0], totals.containsKey(datum[0]) ? totals.get(datum[0]) + new Integer(datum[1]) : datum[1]); or totals.put(datum[0], datum[1] + totals.containsKey(datum[0]) ? totals.get(datum[0]) : 0)

Comment: @program-o-steve no problem - it still works. data edited to include extra brand - see edited answer and updated output

Comment: doesn't belong here but what are the good sources to learn `collections` It has been a year i have learned java but i am not handy with collections

Comment: @tibtof I had a bug, and you're almost correct. I used the `Integer(String)` constructor, and a ternary on `contains()` - see edited code. And thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @program-o-steve Every good java programmer must learn collections! They get used everywhere. fyi, it is actually uncommon these days to use arrays. There are some old APIs that require you to use arrays (eg `java.io.*`) but all "business" logic should use collections wherever possible in preference to arrays.

Comment: yes i know.but can you recommend some sources to learn collections. and what is _fyi_ ?

Comment: @program-o-steve If you are already familiar with the concepts of the different data structures and just want to learn syntax and java specific hints, I recommend the official source: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html). For the basic understanding of data structures, I recommend buying a book or attending a lecture at a nearby technical university. I don't know how it is in your country, but in mine everyone is free to just sit in those. And every university has a first year basic "introduction into algorithms and data structures" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know it a priori, the size will be known just when you'll have finished splitting the strings and doing your math.

In your example in the end `marked.size()` will have the size you are looking for but I'd suggest you to directly use a HashMap so that you won't care about searching for existing elements in linear time and then convert it to an array.

Something like:

```
String[][] names = new String[map.size()];
Set<String> keys = map.keys();
int c = 0;

for (String k : keys)
{
  names[c] = new String[2];
  names[c][0] = k;
  names[c++][1] = map.get(k).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, you want to know the number of distinct names in your array without calling `calculator()`, right? I don't really know if that makes sense as you still have to go through every entry and compare it with a set. But you could do it with a Set:

```
private int getNumberOfEntries(String[][] data) {
  Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
  for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    names.add(data[i][1]);
  }
  return names.size();
}
```

Now you can just call `int n = getNumberOfEntries(data);`...

EDIT: Of course it makes more sense to do the sums in the same step, see Bohemians solution for that.